# Programming language R: meaning of 'weights' parameter in library method 'loess'

Tags: r, loess, non-linear-regression

I use the library method `loess` of the R programming language for non parametric data fitting. The dataset is two-dimensional. I have not found any proper documentation of the method parameter `weights`.

My data points are normally distributed random variables, and I also have an estimate of their respective standard deviations. I am wondering whether the parameter `weights` allows me to supply R with the details of the standard deviations. In other words: I wonder whether the individual weights in `weights` are (relative) measures of data quality, so that the fit can be improved if some measure of data uncertainty is supplied via the parameter `weights`.

EDIT: I suspect the entries in `weights` are used as weights in the weighted least squares regressions of local datasets in the LOESS procedure (maybe as additional weight prefactors for the (position dependent) kernel functions?). This would suggest that for the case of data points which are independent normally distributed random variables, but still have different noise levels (i.e. different standard deviations) (as in my case), the weights should be chosen as `1/\sigma_{i}^2`, where `\sigma_{i}` is the standard deviation of the respective random variable/data point. If someone knows for sure, that would be nice to know.

Comment: In short: yes. That is what you expect from weights. For some intuition see the same argument of e.g. `weighted.mean`. Of course you don't want to use your standard deviations as weights.

Comment: @mts: thank you for the hint regarding weighted.mean. Intuitively I'd use the inverse standard deviation as weight. As I do not know much about the internal workings of R's loess implementation, I am not quite sure if this is a proper choice.

Comment: I'm not sure what is a standard/good choice for the weights, if you don't find anything through google, you should ask on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ as it is not a programming question anymore. If you are interested in what `loess` is doing, consider checking the source code at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page confirms my suspicion:

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/3.1.0/doc/html/Language_Reference/stats/loess.html

Regarding the parameter `weights` of `loess` it says:

> an optional expression for weights to give to **individual observations
>   in the sum of squared residuals that forms the local fitting
>   criterion**. By default, an unweighted fit is carried out. If it is
>   supplied, weights is treated as an expression to evaluate in the same
>   data frame as the model formula. It should evaluate to a non-negative
>   numeric vector. **If the different observations have nonequal variances,
>   weights should be inversely proportional to the variances**.